# Set HTML table rows all at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have code that runs through every row of a html table and updates it with a different row.

Here is the code

```
    function sort(index) {
        var rows = $table.find('tbody tr');
        var a = $table.find('tbody tr');

        //Only sort if it has not been sorted yet and the index not the same
        if(sortedIndex === index){
            for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                a[i].outerHTML = rows[(rows.length - i)-1].outerHTML;
            }
            toggleSorted();
        }else{
            sortedIndex = index;
            rows.sort(naturalSort);

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                a[i].outerHTML = rows[i].outerHTML;
            }
            sortedDown = true;
        }

        $('#${tableId}').trigger('repaginate');
    };
```

What I am trying to do is to instead of going through every single row in the for loop and setting a[i].outterHTML = rows[i].outterHTML; I would like to just set all of the rows at once. Currently it takes about 1.5 seconds to set them and that is very slow.... Only issue is I cannot seem to find a way to do this. Is this actually possible? (It takes 1.5 seconds on large data sets which is what I am working with).

Comment: Are you using this just to sort table data? Its much less expensive to sort the rows than to change the html of them

Comment: I guess you could remove the `tbody`, perform the sort offline and then re-add the tbody to the table

Comment: how about putting the table in a wrapper then just replace the entire table? Process the rows on the server send back one big chunk of html....**should** be a little faster, and will scale better

Comment: Or you could try rewriting your logic so only a single call to `innerHTML` is required to generate the table rows. DOM manipulation should be limited to as few instances as possible, since otherwise things can really slow down. I did a [little test with `innerHTML`](http://jsperf.com/single-vs-multiple-innerhtml-test) to show how performance suffers. Also, my first jsPerf, yay!

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas guys :), I always appreciate every ones input! Gets me thinking how to approach this next time and  what can be done with javascript. Every answer helps to know what is possible! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rows are the same just reordered, you can [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) them with the new order:

```
var $tBody = $table.find('tbody');
var $rows = $tBody.find('tr');

if(sortedIndex === index){
    toggleSorted();

    $tBody.append($rows.get().reverse());
} 
else {
    sortedIndex = index;
    sortedDown = true;

    $tBody.append($rows.get().sort(naturalSort));
}
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates the above: http://jsfiddle.net/k4u45Lnn/1/

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for! You are awesome my friend :). This cut my time down around 2 seconds. The sort only takes around half a second with a lot of data :). Thanks for the help!

Comment: One thing I do not understand is append tho.... Why is it not stacking the data since it is called append?

Comment: @user3585563 From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/) "If an element ... is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)."

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way to "set all of your rows at once" is to loop through all of your rows and perform an operation on each row. There may be some libraries which have methods and functions that make it look like you're doing the operation on all of your rows at one shot, but ultimately if you want to edit every element in a set you need to iterate through the set and carry out the action on each element, seeing as HTML doesn't really provide any way to logically "link" the attributes of your elements.